# How do I have a struct's field be an `Iterator` over `T` elements?

Tags: rust

I want a struct's field to be an `Iterator` over `T` elements, however `Iterator` doesn't have a type parameter. I know I'm trying to do something fundamentally wrong, what though?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Rust, `Iterator` (more specifically `Iterator<Item = T>` where `T` is the type yielded when iterating) is a *trait*. Types that represent iterators implement this trait.

This is an instance of the more general question "how can I store a value of a trait in a struct?". I deliberately phrased the question in an imprecise way -- what we actually want is to store a value of a *type implementing the trait*, and there are broadly two ways to do that.

## Put it in a box

The easiest way is to use a `Box<Iterator<Item = T>>`. The `Box` represents an owned pointer, and when you have a pointer to a trait object, Rust creates a "fat pointer" including runtime information about the type. This way the concrete type of the iterator is not known at compile time.

The definition looks like this:

```
struct IteratorHolder {
    iter: Box<Iterator<Item = u32>>,
}
```

And usage:

```
let ih = IteratorHolder { iter: Box::new(0..10) };
println!("{:?}", ih.iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
```

## Generics

Another way to do the same thing, while avoiding allocating any boxes on the heap, is to use a generic struct. This way we will have some type implementing `Iterator<Item = T>`, and what it is concretely will be determined at compile time.

Definition:

```
struct IteratorHolder<I: Iterator<Item = u32>> {
    iter: I,
}
```

And usage:

```
let ih = IteratorHolder { iter: 0..10 };
println!("{:?}", ih.iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
```

Comment: In Rust 2021, `iter: Box<Iterator<Item = u32>>` would not work. We would need an explicit `dyn` keyword for trait objects i.e. `iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u32>>`.

Comment: Hmm, good point @yottabytt but @Shepmaster is there any policy on that? Are we supposed to update old SO answers when breaking changes are made in editions? _(Personally, I still think the `dyn Trait` syntax is ugly as sin, but I'll try to leave that aside.)_

Comment: I wish we WOULD update them. I came along trying to figure out how to store an iterator in a struct and couldn't figure it out.